# How to pass in information from the host to docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using docker-compose to manage the development environment. One component is an Apache reverse proxy. I set-up httpd-vhosts.conf to include a vhost that actully proxies the request back to the host.

Configured the following way.

```
FROM httpd:2.4
#ssl
ADD ./server.crt /usr/local/apache2/conf/
ADD ./server.key /usr/local/apache2/conf/
ADD ./server-bundle.crt /usr/local/apache2/conf/

#vhosts
ADD ./httpd-vhosts.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/extra

RUN echo "Configuring Vhost" && \
sed -i 's@#Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf@Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf@' /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf

# Exposed ports
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
```

Somehow I need to pass in the HOST's current gateway IP address into the httpd-vhosts.conf

currently this is hard coded like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  
    ProxyPass /http://10.0.2.2:8090/
    ProxyPassReverse /http://10.0.2.2:8090/

    ErrorLog "logs/cf.e-change.co-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/cf.e-change.co-access_log" common       
</VirtualHost
```

If I run the following command 
    `netstat -nr | grep '^0\.0\.0\.0' | awk '{print $2}'`

It gives me the IP I need to pass into the container as ENVIRONMENT variable.

What would be the best to do this?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass environment variables from Docker Compose into the container. E.g. with the following docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'

services:
  test:
    image: busybox
    command: env
    environment:
      - MY_VAR
```

You can then export MY_VAR, or just pass it on the same command line:

```
$ MY_VAR="hello world" docker-compose up
Creating test_test_1
Attaching to test_test_1
test_1  | PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
test_1  | HOSTNAME=a3b5b5bf4afd
test_1  | MY_VAR=hello world
test_1  | HOME=/root
test_test_1 exited with code 0
```

Comment: Hi, thanks this looks good. is there any way to pass things as a result of a script ? I guess I can create a Makefile that passes this info in though

Comment: Not inside of the compose yml, you'd need to make your own wrapper to call compose with the right variables. Note that you aren't limited to compose, there's also `docker run -e MY_VAR busybox env`